# Rails server won't respond to any request outside the local network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, thin, webrick

I'm running Rails con a VM with a bridged interface, it has it's own IP in the local network.

When I start rails in 0.0.0.0:3000 I can access it using the local network IP in the port 3000 without any problem.

The router NAT configuration is to route the port 3000 to the VM.

When I check the port 3000 on http://canyouseeme.org with the Rails server stopped it says the port is closed. With the rails server started it says the port is open. This means, the router is indeed routing to the VM, right?

But when I try to enter the server through my public IP in the port 3000, it won't answer.

I tried changing the server from Thin to Webrick, with the same result.

Also, I tried to run another web server in the port 3000 with he same results. No answer to public requests outside the local network. Yet the port is checked as opened.

Also, UFW is stopped, and anyway I allowed the port 3000.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Some routers don't support loopback, meaning you can't access the public IP from within the LAN. FWIW, I tried this"

```
telnet canyouseeme.org 3000
Trying 8.23.224.110...
```

With no luck.